# AIX: How to list subservers of a specific subsystem which use signal communication?

Tags: unix, daemon, aix, subsystem

I know that we can list the subservers of a subsystem by using the command `lssrc -l -s subsystem_name` command. But this does not work when the subsystem uses the `signal communication` as the communication type with `srcmstr` daemon. Is there an any kind of way to know what are the subservers of a particular subsystem which use `signal` communication? Can we find them by inspecting the subsystem object? If so where is it located?

Comment: Could you please give an example for such a subsystem that uses _signal communication_ and has _subservers_?

Answer (score 0):

Since `lssrc -ls` reports an error when the subsystem only supports signal communication, decide based on the return code:

```
lssrc -l -s portmap > /dev/null || echo portmap only supports signal communication.
```

Alternatively, you can query the ODM for the subsystem's "contact" value equaling 2; this will return a list of subsystems that support signal communication:

```
odmget -q contact=2 SRCsubsys | grep subsysname
```